# Arduino bluetooth HC-05 servo control

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, hc-05

I am using HC-05 Bluetooth module to control two servos. I use Bluetooth terminal in my android phone to control them.

Problem is that myServo1 is moving like I want but I can't control myServo2. Code is reading the variable a but it can't read variable b.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo1;
Servo myServo2;
int servo;
SoftwareSerial BT(2, 3); 
void setup()  
{
myServo1.attach(11);
myServo2.attach(10);
servo = 90;


Serial.begin(9600);
BT.begin(9600);
}
char a; 
char b;
void loop() 
{
 if (BT.available())
{
a=(BT.read());
b = (BT.read());
if (a=='1')
{
  myServo1.write(180);
  delay(50);


}
if (a=='2')
{
  myServo1.write(-180);
  delay(50);


 }
  if (b=='3')
{
  myServo2.write(90);
  delay(50);


}
  if (b=='4')
{
  myServo2.write(-90);
  delay(50);


}
}
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: your sketch has no debugging code .... why are you not printing the values of `a` and `b` to the serial monitor?

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
if(BT.available())
```

that's doing the same as

```
if(BT.available() > 0)
```

But then you are reading 2 bytes, though you cannot be sure, that there are 2 bytes to read. The data is transmitted serially, so even when you send it on your phone in one bunch, it does not get transmitted as bunch.

Try to use

```
if(BT.available() >= 2)
```

Also makes sure, that nothing else gets send over serial besides the numbers (often there is a line ending send implicitly depending on the used app).

Comment: If I use the " if(BT.available() >= 2) " it will mix the whole system

Comment: What do you mean by that? @engineerstudent

Comment: It does not work properly. If I put "1", "2", "3" or "4" it turns one servo randomly. In some cases it doesn't work at all

Comment: Then you also have another problem. Have you confirmed, that the comminication with the HC-05 works correctly? You can do this by using a testsketch, where you forward the received data from bluetooth to the serial monitor. If everything is transmitted correctly, we can rule out that part

Comment: I don't think that there is problem in the connection because if I use "BT.available()>0" and I type "1" or "2" then it work properly and turns the myServo1 between 180 and -180.

Comment: My proposed solution should not result in the observed errating behavior. It just waits for 2 bytes to be actually available, before you read them. Thus I think, that there is something else wrong. Do you really don't send any line ending? That would explain the behavior

Comment: When it send the value then I press enter. Would that cause the error? If so how I fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106049/discussion-between-chrisl-and-engineerstudent).